# Why am I getting an error when summing numbers?

Tags: reactjs

I try to summarize the numbers obtained from props, but I get an error

[image]

```js
 // my numbers
  const onPostIncomeData = () => {
    return invoiceList.map(i => {
 return i.amount;
    })
  };

  const arrSum = arr => arr.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0)
  
  // error
  arrSum(onPostIncomeData());
  
  // onPostIncomeData() console.log
  [3, 1]
```

Comment: `console.log(invoiceList)` before using it, may be its value is `undefined`

Comment: Is these numbers from a async function?

Answer (score 1):

Add `useEffect` to check if `invoiceList` prop contains data

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!invoiceList) return;
  arrSum(onPostIncomeData());
}, [invoiceList])
```

Comment: Saldahe. Uragon talaga

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the invoiceList is undefined at first. So, on my solution, I added a default value for onPostIncomeData parameter. That ensure that the code will not break unless you pass another type than array.

```
const onPostIncomeData = (arr = []) => {
  return arr.map(i => {
    return i.amount;
  });
};

const arrSum = (arr) => arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

arrSum(onPostIncomeData(invoiceList));
```

Hope it helps. Cheers